# How to limit the access of Federated users on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to limit the access of IAM Roles created by federated users in our organization's SANDBOX AWS account.

For example, the SANDBOX AWS account is used by many people via federated user IAM Role (we use Azure Active directory). For security reasons, IT does not allow a federated user to create any IAM Roles to avoid users messing with resources created by other people. Only IT can create roles. I find that very limiting.

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to change the federated IAM Role so that it can create IAM Roles but those roles can only "see" the resources that each federated user created.

[image]

Comment: There is no concept in AWS of "resource ownership". For example, if an S3 bucket is created by User A, there is no link between the bucket and User A. Thus, it is not possible to only allow users to "see" resources created by a particular User. You can possibly emulate this behaviour by using Tags, but the difficultly is enforcing the correct tagging of resources when the resources are created. Then, add the requirement that you want to separately identify users who are all using a shared "POCUser" identity and it becomes even harder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It does help to know that the problem at hand is not easily solved. I was hoping that there would be a straightforward improvement to our workflow but it does sound like it won't be possible. 

We would be better off going through the "manual" process of working with IT to create the IAM Roles our team needs.